# Tracking French long stay visa application status online

Tags: france, visa

I am looking to find a way to track my French long stay visa application. I had my visa interview/appointment on 3/24/2014 at the [Consulate general of France in Chicago](http://www.consulfrance-chicago.org/).

From previous experiences with other visa processes like the USA where I was able to track my visa application status, I am unable to find any way to do so for the French long stay visa.

Apparently, it [is possible in Australia](https://pastel.diplomatie.gouv.fr/VisaNET-Consultation-Internet/html/frameset/frameset.html?lcid=280) to do so via the consulate's website.

Am I missing something? Is there NO way I can track my application's status online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the website is in fact a central database, you only need a link from the right consulate because the first five characters in your receipt number can't be entered manually. Here is [Chicago's page](https://pastel.diplomatie.gouv.fr/VisaNET-Consultation-Internet/html/frameset/frameset.html?lcid=82). (I haven't tried it myself, obviously.)

Unfortunately, the consulates' websites are not unified and vary greatly in quality and I couldn't find a full list with the right links. It seems possible to fiddle with the last parameter in the URL to find the correct page directly (consulates are apparently more-or-less in alphabetical order).

Comment: Thank you. The tracking pages says the following: "Your visa application is still being processed. Please check the status of your visa application again at a later date." . **However**, I find a severe disconnect because the consulate emailed me saying: "No you cannot track the application. We will notify you when the visa is ready". Strange and frustrating at the same time.

Comment: @drN I don't actually know how this works behind the scenes, it's possible that some consulates update the database while others don't.

Comment: Yes, that could be the case (non uniform update of details).

Comment: The London consulate said that to me (and they do have an option on the website). My impression was that they do not want people to be checking / constantly asking. They just say 'trust the process' and to stop worrying about it. Which was hard in my case, as my visa was 3 weeks late...